# Minimum development environment for sharepoint 2007 webparts

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I know there are already a couple of questions out there about sharepoint development environments, but I was wondering if there's a shortcut if all I want to do is develop a relatively simple webpart. Do I still have to create a virtual machine with windows server, install sharepoint, sql server, wss etc., etc. or is there some easy way to get up and running more quickly?

In short, what's the absolute minimum environment I need to develop a webpart for sharepoint 2007?

Comment: Just curious - but why are you looking for the minimum rather than the least hassle/most productive? I mean I saw the 'relatively simple' but even then I think the work of setting up VMWare, a 2003 server and installing WSS (no need for SQL) will pay dividends.

Comment: I agree and disagree. If you go down this path for a SharePoint developer that's fine but don't do it for everyone that wants to build web parts for SharePoint. You only need a few SharePoint devs to handle web part development as a company. You can have as many ASP.NET devs as you wish building web parts and then the few SharePoint devs can do the final move to SP (repository switching, in-mem/mock object switches, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are willing to put up with some serious drawbacks (like not being able to debug your web part) you will have to build a virtual machine with windows server.

The minimum development environment is :
-Windows Server + SharePoint (WSS or MOSS) + Visual Studio

SQL Express will be installed with Visual Studio.

It does take time to setup your first virtual machine, but once you have it you can back it up and use it for every new project. While you could probably develop a web part on your own machine by copying a bunch of DLLs and hacking something up, it would almost definitely not be worth it. Being able to debug and to deploy fast will make your development way faster.

Even if you don't *need* it, I still recommend that you install [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) as part of your minimal environment. Takes 2 minutes to install and it will save you hours.

Comment: Also, if you want to make life even easier for yourself, you can use the Visual Studio 2008 extensions for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0, v1.3.  You can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=B2C0B628-5CAB-48C1-8CAE-C34C1CCBDC0A&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

If you can run a virtual machine with 2GB, you should be fine for web part development. I say virtual machine because I doubt you'll want to run windows server on your desktop.

Also, remember that your web parts can use the ASP.NET WebPart object and you can develop that on whatever environment you wish. If you abstract out your code enough you should be able to save SP object model code until the last possible step which would cut down your time on an actual SP environment.

Comment: Would I still be able to preview/debug my web part? Or would I have to develop in the dark, then deploy the webpart to a sharepoint server in order to test it even if it doesn't use any sharepoint specifice features (apart from authorization)?

Comment: With the correct abstractions you should be able to mock up anything you need from the SharePoint world and run it in VS with in memory data. Now you will have to setup a web part testing app with the personalization database, a web part manager, some zones, etc. but that's pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute minimum is ASP.NET 2.0, a text editor, a compiler, and makecab.exe.

SharePoint web parts inherit from [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), so as long as you don't need to access the SharePoint API, you can create the class and associated XML files using any configuration that has the .NET runtime.

However, you'll probably want to use Visual Studio. Many recommend [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/), but I use a customized version of [STSDEV](http://stsdev.codeplex.com/) that will work on my Windows XP laptop. Visual Studio helps with the writing of the code, while WSPBuilder or STSDEV help with the creation of the supporting XML files and the WSP solution package file.

If you need to use the SharePoint API, you can copy the necessary DLLs from a server with SharePoint installed. Place the DLLs locally and then add them to your project references.

You will not be able to debug the web part if it calls the SharePoint API. Personally, I'd rather be able to use my computer than having debugging. In place of debugging, I use logging. While developing, I create an Announcements list named Log and write anything I want logged into that list.

Answer (score 0):

The Environment you need to have for developing simple web part is:

Visual studio with WSP Builder add on.

Develop The webpart and build it. When you build the webpart you get the webpartname.wsp.

Take this file to the machine where you have the Sharepoint installed and you can Deploy it using sstadm.

If anyone wants detailed info, please let me know.
Hari Gillala