# Hosting Sharepoint and SQL Server off same server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

Is it possible to host Sharepoint and SQL Server off the same server for small time testing. Environment would be set up for purely education purposes. Non-production. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a simple virtual environment (I quiet like VirtualBox) and then run a server operating system on there, install SQL Server (if it is only for testing SQL Server express would be sufficient) and then install SharePoint.  When you have installed SharePoint you will be better removing the default web application it adds for you and then adding your own as you will be able to link the new application's database easily to the instance of SQL on your SQL server.

Don't forget that if you are looking at using SharePoint 2010 it all has to be 64bit...

[Minimum development environment for sharepoint 2007 webparts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195356/minimum-development-environment-for-sharepoint-2007-webparts/)

Hope this helps anyway...

Comment: Thanks, I am going to give this a try.

Comment: Alternatively install Windows Server 2008 into your VirtualBox VM and then install WSS 3.0. I didn't need to install SQL Server that way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. We do this also. Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks. Any special instructions for set up?

Comment: Install the SQL server first. AFAIK the SharePoint server needs a reference to a SQL server also, so you can just give him the one on localhost.

Comment: I'm doing this in a VM using SQL Express as the database engine.  I can confirm that this works.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but SQL server likes to use up all the RAM, making sharepoint really slow, and sometimes with sharepoint 2010 it crashes the web application.

Try to limit how much RAM sql server takes

http://blog.stevehorn.cc/2007/10/limit-memory-usage-in-sql-server-2005.html